# Streaming video file from flask server to react js client

Tags: python, reactjs, video-streaming

I am creating a "Youtube Clone" using Python Flask on the backend and React JS on the server side, and I currently need to stream the video from a file on the server.

This is what I currently have:

```
@app.route('/api/video/<string:video_id>')
def ShowVideo(video_id):
    video = Video.query.filter_by(id = video_id).first() #"Video" is the video database (using SQLAlchemy)
    if video is None:
        return {"return":"401"} #video doesn't exist in database
   #return ??
```

now I have the video id and path in the database, and I need to stream it over http to a React JS website

---

I've seen people using OpenCV to stream, and put an image in the JS client, but from what I've seen it does not work with a video file already on the computer (I can be mistaken, I'm not sure).

---

Another thing I've seen is using JS to send the video directly to the browser (like in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CiGnubZC5cs), but I don't think this will work for my circumstances)

Does anyone have any idea?